# background color change on hover with background-size

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color

I have the following code:

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    div.testy {
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    div.testy:hover {
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="testy" style="height:100px; 
background: url('down.png') no-repeat; background-size:contain;">
    aa
</div>
```

`'down.png'` is an image with a transparent background. What I wanted to do was have the color of the background change while still keeping the image in front of the color.

The previous code does almost everything right, except that when I hover the mouse over the `div`, nothing happens.

**QUESTION:** Why might it be that the hovering and the background color change are not working?

**Here is a jsfiddle link with the problem happening:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sdsze2fv/

Comment: http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/Nrbmzx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `background:` for the `"background image"`. Differentiate `background image` and `background color` by using `background-color` and `background-image` respectively.

```css
div.testy {
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    div.testy:hover {
        background-color:red;

    }
```

```html
<div class="testy" style="height:100px; 
background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif'); 
background-size:contain;">
    aa
</div>
```

Comment: Works now, thanks. Interestingly enough, repeat also has to be taken out for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you already defined your `background` inline in your html.
Inline styles always override styles set in a css file unless you have added `!important` to the style.

I recommend that you only set `background-image` in your inline style and then `background-color` in your rule in the CSS-file.

```css
div.testy {
  border:1px solid black;
}

div.testy:hover {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="testy" style="height:100px; 
background-image: url('down.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain;">
    aa
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background you are setting inline is overriding the one in the css rule. Inline styles always override anything (except stuff with !important). If you remove the inline and put it in a rule, it will work. Or another method is included in this

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zLv31Lco/)

in this we are saying 'hey, i want the bkgrnd image to be this'...not the background...because background includes everything from image, color, repeat etc. Its the shorthand. So you are technically setting the bkgrnd color there too...which is why its over riding your hover.

Here is the other option...remove from inline and put it into the rule...as is....then it also works

[JSFIDDLE2](https://jsfiddle.net/f721eedx/)

```
div.testy {
   border:1px solid black;
   height: 100px;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: orange;
   background:  url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Gluecksklee_(transparent_background)2.png') no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
}

div.testy:hover {
   background-color:red;
}
```